# Feincms mixing content types

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views, feincms

I have a question and i want to know if i can mix 2 existing contenTypes together into one custom contenType. I need my own content type with contenType RichTextContent and ImageContent so that i can use a special template to show an image right and text left.

Is this possible ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible. I've written my own custom contenttypes for similar reasons. You should review the code for the RichTextContent model in `<Python egg dir>/feincms/content/richtext/models.py`

You'll want to implement your own model class, and override the `render()` method to use `django.template.loader.render_to_string()` to load the template you want.